# Unable to launch an EC2 image as a Micro Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

The good people at OSQA [created](http://meta.osqa.net/questions/6211/is-there-an-amazon-image-ami-with-osqa-on-linux) an Amazon image ("us-east-1", ID "ami-24e7114d"), as a micro instance. When I try to launch this instance, I only get options "large" and above - I don't see any "micro" or "small" options.

Any idea why is this / how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to launch the instance via ElasticFox. As soon as I moved to using the web console, I successfully found and launched a micro instance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have 2 problems causing your issues:

1. The image is 64-bit, so you do not
   see the "small" option as that only
   supports 32-bit images.
2. The image in not EBS backed, so you cannot launch it as a micro instance. The image will need to be converted to an EBS-backed volume, instead of ephemeral storage in order to be used as a micro image. See [this](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2010-11-15/UserGuide/index.html?Concepts_BootFromEBS.html) for more info on the differences.